# NODE.JS accessing functions within an EJS template

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, ejs

I have a scripts.js file that includes a function inside that i want to access within an EJS templates.

in the templates i included a header, in the header I added a script rel to scripts.js

```
<script src="/scripts/scripts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I tested it though console.log("test") and when the template is being called I see "test" appears in the console.

when I try to call an actual function (verify_data)  within the EJS template i get an error verify_data is not defined.
the error code within the EJS looks like this:

```
<p><em>Submited By <%= verify_data(results.user.username) %></em></p>
```

the function check if the argument passed is null/undefined, if yes the data returns if not "n/a" string returns instead.

How do i access JS functions directly within EJS template ?

Thanks,

Comment: You're mixing Backend scriptlet with Javascript from the client (i.e: browser).

Comment: The question if there is a solution for this, run call js functions directly from within  EJS template ?

Comment: No, is not possible.

Comment: Thx for the answer Ele,  I recon the data  validation take place only on the actual routes ? before passing the argument to template ?

Comment: Yes, it's a better approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're not using a SPA framework, you need to add a tag which will be either replaced by the function or to contain the data you want to store.

Look at this code snippet

```html
<p><em>Submited By <span id='userData'></span></em></p>

<script>
//This is the script.js
function verify_data(userName) {
  return `My data with '${userName}'`;
}
</script>

<script>
  let data = verify_data("EleFromStack"); // assuming <%=results.user.username%> = "EleFromStack"
  document.querySelector("#userData").textContent = data;
</script>
```